# Fail to create "empty" MongoDb Documents with DBRef using Spring boot MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to Create a MongoDb Document that have an DBRef in it 
I prepared a sample setup to illustrate the problem, as the real life sample is to long

My data classes :

```
@Document(value = "person")
class Person(
    var id: String?,
    var name:String?,
    ...
    var mainAddressId: String?,  // Used quickly find the firs address (I'm lazy)
    @DBRef(db = "mydatabase")
    var address: List<Address>?
)

@Document(collection = "address")
class Address(
    @Id var id: String?,
    var addressLabel: String?,
    var number: String?,
    var street: String?,
    var neighborhood: String?,
    var locality: String?, // City / Town / Village
    var region: String?, // Region / Province / State
    var country: String?,
    var code: String?, // Zip Code
    var google_place_id: String?,
    var timestamp: Date
)
```

In a @Component class I seed my address first NOTE: the ID is in the seed as its test data! if I omit the Id MondoDb generate a new ID for me (_id:ObjectId())

```
...
addressDocument.add(
                Address(
                    id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199",
                    addressLabel = "Home",
                    number = "1",
                    street = "Microsoft Way",
                    neighborhood = "Redmond",
                    locality = "King County",
                    region = "Washington",
                    country = "United States",
                    code = "98052",
                    google_place_id = "JVQC+QM Redmond, Washington, USA",
                    timestamp = Date()
                )
            )
...
```

My Application "build" this record by slowly collecting all the data
I need to persist the first screen that only capture `name` and some other stuff not shown here and then I need to create the Document

**My difficulty is** when I create the `List<Address> = Null` the Address Document is not created thus I get no `ObjectId` created as MongoDb does not save `null` values .. Some crashes later as Kotlin complain about `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: null` on this line
`addressDBRef.add(addressRepository.findById(person.addressId!!).orElse(null))`

```
...
val addressDBRef = ArrayList<Address>()
            addressDBRef.add(addressRepository.findById(person.addressId!!).orElse(null))

            val newPerson = Person(
                id = null,
                name = person.name,
                lastName = person.lastName,
                ...
                addressId = person.addressId,
                address = addressDBRef
            )
```

even

```
address = listOf(Address(
                    id=null,
                    addressLabel = "edit me please",
                    number = null,
                    street = null,
                    neighborhood = null,
                    locality = null,
                    region = null,
                    country = null,
                    code = null,
                    google_place_id = null,
                    timestamp = Date()
                )),
```

does not work!

I have tried `Optional(List<Address>)` to test for `null` event but the null record is meant to be there so I can add the content later!

Maybe my approach must be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution !

I first create the Address record with a "Dummy" value in one field, in my case I have used the field `addressLabel = "home"`

```
val addressDocument = Address(
                addressLabel = "Home",
                number = null,
                street = null,
                neighborhood = null,
                locality = null,
                region = null,
                country = null,
                code = null,
                google_place_id = null,
                timestamp = Date()
            )

            val newAddress = addressRepository.insert(addressDocument)
```

this successfully creates a document with a new `ObjectId`
then I insert that into the person document

```
            val newPerson = Person(
                id = null,
                name = person.name,
                lastName = person.lastName,
                ...
                addressId = newAddress.id,
                address = listOf(newAddress),
            )
```

This works in all tests I could do!